# box-api unable to get auth_token

Tags: box-api

I am trying to develop an integration with box. I am using "box-api", "~> 0.2.2" gem. I have  an api key.

```
box_object = Box::Api.new("j7p3zz29xgva8t52lgoptyxuavtji66y")
ticket = box_object.get_ticket
auth_key= box_object.get_auth_token(ticket[:ticket])
```

i am getting this exception
Box::Api::NotAuthorized: not_logged_in

Can anyone suggest what is going wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the `ticket` is used to construct a URL to which your app must redirect the user.  This is the first leg of the v1 authentication process.  This [documentation](http://developers.box.com/v1-authentication/) provides a guide.

Comment: so how can a single app be available to all the box users so that they can install and allow access if they need...

Comment: You must redirect the user to Box's website, where they log in and authorize your app to access their data.  Box will then redirect them back to your app's page with an authorization token in the query string. (This is explained in the guide that I linked to.)  Your app will need to store that authorization token on a per-user basis and use it to execute API operations for that user.

Answer (score 0):

Apart from checking the above answers, also ensure that box admin has approved an app before it can be used.

Refer to . - https://community.box.com/t5/How-to-Guides-for-Admins/Enabling-Custom-Built-Applications/ta-p/2188